# Routing key not matching

Tags: rabbitmq

I am successfully publishing to an exchange with the routing key `GetToDosCommand.todo_rss` , the log message is

```
[12:11:59] [$20] [DEBUG] [BaseBusClient`1]: Initiating publish for message 'GetToDosCommand' on exchange 'commands' with routing key GetToDosCommand.todo_rss.
```

I have bound different queues to the exchange mentioned above with different routing keys that I expect to work , but only the catch queue receives any messages

```
queue - routing key
  get1 - GetToDosCommand.todo_rss
  get2 - GetToDosCommand.#
  catch - #
```

Why aren't the other queues getting the messages ?

Comment: You'll have to share the binding definitions for your queues - `rabbitmqctl list_bindings`

Comment: @LukeBakken Interesting , they are , indeed , unexpected values . I will try to create the exchanges and queues manually and bind them ...more to come